# C++11 Template and alias declaration

Tags: templates, c++11, alias

I'm going crazy.
I'm trying to create an Allocator and I wrote this definition in header file.

```
template<typename T>
class Allocator
{
    using size_type = size_t;
    using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using value_type = T;

  //others stuff
  // Get address of a reference
  pointer address(reference x) const;
  ...
};
```

After that, I tried to write the definition in .cpp file like:

```
template<typename T>
pointer Allocator<T>::address(reference x) const
{
    return &x;
}
```

but is wrong.
I tried to write also:

```
template<typename T>
Allocator<T>::pointer Allocator<T>::address(reference x) const
{
    return &x;
}
```

but is wrong in the same manner.

What is the right definition of the method with the template alias?

Thank you for help.

Comment: C++11 allocators can be much, much simpler than that.

Comment: word of warning: *"After that, I tried to write the definition in .cpp file"* don't put the definition in a cpp file, it should reside in a header file

Comment: "I'm going crazy. I'm trying to create an Allocator" -- said every person who has ever tried to make a working C++ Allocator. Seriously though, look into how much simpler it is to make them with C++11 and now C++14 (especially the sized version of `operator delete`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option #1

```
template <typename T>
typename Allocator<T>::pointer Allocator<T>::address(reference x) const
//~~~~~^
{
    return &x;
}
```

#### Option #2

```
template <typename T>
auto Allocator<T>::address(reference x) const -> pointer
//~^                                          ~~~~~~~~~^
{
    return &x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @PiotrS. Just a quick one too: does the C++14 need the ->pointer or is needed only for C++11?

Comment: @Chris leaving just `auto` (in C++14) without `-> pointer` would deduce the result type based on the `&x` expression's type